# HDMI outputting only 640x480, with black boarder

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi, display-resolution

AU. Been googling this for 2 days now, trying various fixes which succeeded in only causing an Nvidia persistent error on boot. Although I did manage to increase the resolution at some point, the black border still existed.

PC is connected via hdmi to an LG tv. I had to install using nosetmode as the hdmi signal would drop during the ubuntu splash screen, if that makes a difference.

xrandr fails to get size of gamma, but if it manages to add the higher resolution, it still displays as 640x480 and I only see a corner. This is a fresh install of 18.04.

Some command examples:

```
    snow-white@snow-white:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00* 
snow-white@snow-white:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for snow-white: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 3]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:dc80(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Ca you check the river version: `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`.

Comment: @mikewhatever terminal gives no response with dpkg -l | grep nvidia

Comment: ...then the question is "How did you install the driver?", and is it, perhaps the wrong version?